# How do I dynamically add content from an array and a multidimensional array to a textfield?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, textfield

I am working on an interactive quiz type game using arrays and multidimensional arrays.

I am trying to make a dynamic textfield say "the current question" + "Sorry, the correct answer is..." + "the second answer in the first string of answers in the array".

I think I am pretty close, but there is an error in the syntax.

Here is the line of code where I try to do this:

```
questionHolder.question.text=(String (cat4Questions[0]) + "Sorry, the correct answer is "+ String (cat4Answers[0,2]));
```

I am getting this error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1030: Stack depth is unbalanced. 1 != 0.
```

I would be happy if someone could recommend a different phrasing of my syntax that will yield positive results.

Thanks! Graeme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be here : `cat4Answers[0,2]`. The right syntax to access multidimensional arrays is array[a][b] and not array[a, b].

Assuming your array contains the right answer for question 0 at index 2, you can access that like this `cat4Answers[0][2]`.